# Datalist input type with formtastic is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, formtastic

I am using active admin in my application with rails version `3.2.22.2`. I am using formtastic version `~> 2.0`. I tried to have a text field with autocomplete option, similar to HTML `datalist`. When I included

```
 <%= f.input :fav_book,:as => :datalist,:collection => books.pluck(:product) %>
```

it throws error as `Unable to find input class for datalist`. Is there  any way to achieve the same

Comment: You need formtastic starting from 3.1.0. Before this version there was no `as: :datalist` option. Or you can use `as: :select` with activeadmin_addons gem - it will convert all selects to Select2 fields

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, is there any other ways of achieving the same